# Trouble in rendering state of parent component before child component gets the state as props

Tags: reactjs

I am sending state value from parent component to child component as props, but I child component updates before the parent component's state is set.

### This is in the parent component

```
  handleSubmit = function(e){
              e.preventDefault();
            this.setState({table: true});
            this.setState({rows: [
              {
                id: 1,
                name: this.state.name,
                email: this.state.email,
                phone: this.state.phone
              }
            ]
          } , () => {console.log(this.state.rows)});
            this.setState({updateInTable: true} , () => {console.log(this.state.updateInTable)})
            this.setState({submit: false});
          }
```

---

This is in the child component

```
  componentDidUpdate() {
          console.log('From table '+this.props.updateInTable);
          if(this.props.updateInTable){
            console.log('Coming from table '+this.props.rows);
          }
        }
```

---

I am sending these as props

```
           <Table
                 table={this.state.table}
                 name={this.state.name}
                 rows={this.state.rows}
                 updateInTable={this.state.updateInTable}
                 />
```

### These are returning from console

From table false

From table true

Coming from table [object Object]

[Object]

true

---

I expect [Object], true which are in parent component to be printed first and then From table false , From table true

---

CodePen Link: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZXOrPE

Answer (score 0):

It is not guaranteed that when you change the children component are updated immediately. In fact updates are usually batched for performance.

Calling `setState` multiple times in a row in the same function is considered sort of a bad practice, you can/should actually group the whole process in one `setState` call

Answer (score 0):

Expanding upon what Mario F answered, the [React documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate) does in fact state:

> `setState()` does not always immediately update the component. It may
>   batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading `this.state`
>   right after calling `setState()` a potential pitfall.

Instead, try setting your state in a single call...

```js
handleSubmit = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  this.setState({
    table: true,
    rows: [{
      id: 1,
      name: this.state.name,
      email: this.state.email,
      phone: this.state.phone
    }],
    updateInTable: true,
    submit: false
  });
}
```

If you do in fact need the state to update synchronously, consider using `componentDidUpdate` or a `setState` callback, which are guaranteed to fire after the update has been applied as described in the documentation provided.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what Mario F and T Porter said, multiple setState are batched in React. Multiple setStates should be combined to one. But in your case even if we combine multiple setState into one output remains same. That is because componentDidUpdate() method in child component is called twice onSubmit.

onClick Submit button two functions are called in following order:

- **submitClic**k = function(){
              this.setState({ cancel: false});
            }

When submitClick is called componentDidUpdate() is called for the first time and **From table false** is logged as this.props.updateInTable is false at this time.

- **handleSubmit** (when the submit event bubbled to form)

When handleSubmit is called multiple setStates are batched and componentDidUpdate() is called again and at this time this.props.updateInTable is true. Therefore, the output logged is:

**From table true**

**Coming from table [object Object]**

The setState callbacks are always executed after lifecycle of child component is done, that is why folowing is consoled last.

**[Object]**

**true**

I hope it answers your question.

Comment: Thank you very much ! You gave me an idea of what is happening!